# Disabling Context menu for a JavaFX Stage

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, contextmenu, javafx-8

I am trying to disable the keyboard shotcut to open the context menu of a stage which shows minimize, maximize, close etc., But the context menu is not being disabled.

```
homeStage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void handle(final KeyEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE && ev.isAltDown()) {
            LOGGER.info("Context menu diabled");
        }
    }
});
```

But still when overriding the functionality also , the context menu pops up.

Comment: afaik, that menu is controlled by the OS, so I doubt that you can disable it

Comment: As @kleopatra already pointed out, this is managed by Windows and not by JavaFX, have you added a `System.out.println("Event hit!");` statement to see whether that event actually gets passed to JavaFX?

Comment: I have tried but i cant diable it.Even i got to know that this is controlled by windows.